# How to properly code a For-Loop and a Do-While Loop in a multiplication table in C#?

Tags: c#, loops

I hate to be so helpless and by no means am I asking anyone to do my homework for me, but for some strange reason, I am having a hard time with this assignment and Loops in general have always given me a lot of trouble. But I am still a bit new at C# and OOP.

I am simply supposed to modify some of the code (the instructor and I already wrote some) by modifying the nested while-loops into nested **for-loops**. and also modify the nested while-loops into **do-while loops**. Loops are obviously very important parts of programming, but I think I seem to learn differently and am wondering what is missing...

Code:

```
namespace CS10b
{
    public partial class frmCS10b : Form
    {
        public frmCS10b()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            //Outer loop goes down the rows
            r = 1;   //initialize r
            while (r < 10)
            {
                //Inner loop goes across the columns
                c = 1;    //initialize c
                while (c < 10)
                {
                    intResult = r * c;

                    if (intResult < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space
                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

                    txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                    c++;  //increment c
                }

                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
                r++;  //increment r
            }
        }


        //Modify the nested while loops used above to nested do-while loops
        private void btnDoWhileLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            txtTable.AppendText("Nested do-while loops to be developed");  //Delete this after implementation

            //Outer loop goes down the rows
            //initialize r
            //do
            {
                //Inner loop goes across the columns
                //initialize c
                //do
                {
                    intResult = r * c;

                    if (intResult < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space
                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

                    txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                    //increment c
                } //while (c < 10);

                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
                //increment r
            } //while (r < 10);
        }


        //Modify the nested while loops used above to nested for loops
        private void btnForLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = 0; //row
            int c = 0; //column
            int intResult;
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear();    //clear the text box
            txtTable.Refresh();  //refresh the form before exiting the method
            Thread.Sleep(1000);  //wait one second to see the clear text box

            txtTable.AppendText("Nested do-while loops to be developed");  //Delete this after implementation


            //Outer loop goes down the rows



            //for (initialize r; Boolean Condition, increment r)
             {

                //Inner loop goes across the columns
                //for (initialize c; Boolean Condition, increment c)
                {
                    intResult = r * c;

                    if (intResult < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space
                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space

                    txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
                }

                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
            }
        }


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }//end of form
}//end of namespace
```

This SHOULD be easy, but loops I have never done do-while and for-loops. Thank you.

Comment: A do-while-loop is the same as a while-loop with the one difference that a do-while will *always* run at least once. Just try `do { Console.WriteLine("will be displayed"); } while (false);` versus `while (false) { Console.WriteLine("won't be displayed"); }`. A for-loop combines setup, checking and end-of-turn-action into one. `for ([setup]; [check condition]; [do stuff at end-of-turn]) { \\ ... }`. In your case, something like `for (int r = 1; r < 10; r++) { \\ inner loop }`

Comment: See also the MSDN entries for: [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ch45axte.aspx), [while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) and [do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/370s1zax.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace while-loops with for-loops ?

For-Loop :

```
for(int r = 1; r < 10; r++)
   {
      for(int c = 1; c < 10; c++)
         {
            intResult = r * c;
            if (intResult < 10)
            strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
            else
            strSpace = " ";   //one space
            txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space
            txtTable.AppendText(intResult.ToString());  //insert result
         }
      txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
   }
```

Do-While-Loop : (not sure about this one)

```
int r = 1;
do
    {
        int c = 1;
        do
             {
                  //Your code
             } while c < 10
    } while (r < 10);
```